# ASUS TUF A15 FA507RE laptop Wi-Fi connection continuously keeps randomly and intermittently disconnecting from the internet

Tags: wireless-networking

My ASUS TUF A15 FA507RE laptop Wi-Fi connection (MediaTek Wi-Fi 6 MT7921 Wireless LAN Card) continuously keeps randomly and intermittently disconnecting from the internet.

Note:  Latest MediaTek Inc device driver installed for MediaTek Wi-Fi 6 MT7921 Wireless LAN Card.

Windows Wireless Network Adapter Diagnostics reports:

```
Issues found - Your computer appears to be correctly configured, 
but the device or resource (DNS server) is not responding
```

My laptop reports all is working great except for the above problem.

SFC Scan, DISM Scan, CCleaner, Advanced System Care, User Benchmark etc all report my laptop is working great with no problems.

Downloaded AMD Automatic Software Installer from the AMD official site and downloaded the latest AMD Radeon Graphics and Chipset Drivers. (https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/faq/rsx2-install#faq-Download-Software-and-Drivers-)

Driver Booster v10.2 Pro reports my laptop drivers are all up to date and report no problems.

MyASUS online ONE-CLICK DIAGNOSIS reports no problems found.

Note: I purchased my laptop with W11 but down-graded to W10 as more comfortable with W10 environment for now.

I have researched the internet for many hours and tried the many suggestions from my internet research to resolve my problem but without any success.

Can anyone please help to resolve my Wi-Fi randomly and intermittently disconnecting from the internet problem as I am getting very frustrated?

Comment: It states, "device or resource (DNS server) is not responding." Have you tried using another DNS resolution service, e.g., Cloudflare, https://privacy.net/set-up-cloudflare-dns-how-to/ ?

Comment: Thankyou for your reply and advice.

I followed your enclosed URL instructions to use another DNS server but this still did not resolve my problem.

My laptop Wi-Fi connection is still intermittently disconnecting from the internet.

Comment: I have also tried the below suggestions but my problem is still occurring.  

1. Reset the network of your computer..
netsh int ip reset
netsh winsock reset
netsh winhttp reset proxy
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns

2. Uninstall and reinstall your mouse (not sure of why this suggestion?)

3. Perform a clean boot to check if the network is fine, this is a troubleshooting step. In this mode, we can further confirm whether it is caused by system problem or third-party software or personalized settings 

Do you have any other suggestions please?

Comment: Thanks all.  Resolved problem. Added power tab to wireless card in Device Manager...

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with Wi-Fi, bad ping, disconnections - move the SSD to another slot, it blocks Wi-Fi and overheats it.